# How to fix Ngons?

Tags: modeling

my mesh has alot of Ngons, any tips on how to fix them? Making them quads would be great.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there's any magic trick, but you can make a Limited Dissolve to get rid of useless edges and use the knife tool to draw quads (K to activate, Z to cut through, C to cut orthogonally, E to keep on, Enter to confirm=

Comment: Fix what? Ngon? unless you have shading issue or want your model to deform, Ngon is good enough to go. Anyway, try triangulate all faces (Faces > Triangulate Faces or Ctrl+T) and then make all of them quads (Faces > Tris to Quads or Alt+J). Or just do it manually, dissolve some edges, using vertex or edge slide, etc..

Comment: Thanks guys, i managed to triangulate the faces